# How to make a:hover, hyperlinked color gradient?

Tags: css, hover

I want make this effection:
`a{color:#000;}` , when I make a a:hover, the hyperlinked color gradient from `#00C` to `#000`, the gradient time maybe 1 second. 
Is it could be make only be css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this cannot be done in CSS. Except maybe with a Behaviour, but those are IE only and even then are pretty shady. You'll need a bit of JavaScript to register onMouseOver and onMouseOut events, which will handle the fade.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with css. You can do this with javascript. 
Take a look at this jquery tutorial (it was very useful in something alike we did once) :

http://blog.ajdeskta.com/tutorials/link-hover-effects-with-jQuery/